# Next Api Routes data is not sent

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm using Next.js 13's api route. I'm sending a string array to the route and I want this to be output as a return value in the response. However all I get I get the error below. In the Chrome debugger I don't see the array that should actually be sent either. If I change the whole thing to a simple string in the FormData, nothing is sent either

```
const sendToAPI = () => {
const data = new FormData();
data.append("urls", JSON.stringify(downloadUrls));

fetch("/api/uploadToMongoDB", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};
```

/api/uploadToMongoDB.ts

```
export default async function handler(
req: NextApiRequest,
res: NextApiResponse
) {

 if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    res.status(405).send({ message: 'Only POST requests allowed' })
    return
  }

  const body = await JSON.parse(req.body)


  res.status(200).json({ message: `You submitted the following data: ${body}` })

}
```

> error - pages\api\uploadToMongoDB.ts (14:30) @ parse
> error - Error [SyntaxError]: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
body: JSON.stringify({ urls: downloadUrls })
```

instead of using FormData. FormData isn't JSON and therefore the conversion cannot be made. If you need to have FormData in your implementation, consider using

```
body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data));
```

If it still doesn't work, please let me know!